# Linux: What's the debug information format "stabs" short for in English?

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, binary, format

Under linux, gcc --gstabs helps to generate debug information.
But what's "stabs" short for? I searched google only to find explanations on what stabs do, but what does it stand for, literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Mark Linton's paper [The Evolution of Dbx](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.5985):

> Berkeley Unix stores symbol information in a format called “stabs” (for *s*ymbol *tab*le entrie*s*).

They may be hard to see, but I've tried to reproduce the italicized portions of the words from the formatted paper, *s*, *tab*, and *s*.